# Is there a single-word antonym for "Opportunity"?

Tags: antonyms

We would often say there is "an opportunity" somewhere, but I can't find any evidence of a word to describe a dearth of opportunity. It's derived from opportune, which has inopportune as a negation, but the shape of an inopportunity doesn't seem correct and is very clunky to say. Is there a single word meaning "no opportunity"?

Comment: In many cases the antonym is "prejudice".

Comment: Alternatively, there's "risk" (something which may happen, but with a negative value, and therefore to be avoided instead of aimed for).

Comment: Are you looking for merely a lack of opportunity ("dearth", as you put it) or an abundance of inopportune (i.e. inconvenient, inappropriate) conditions? The two are distinctly different - I may not have any opportunities, but that doesn't mean I'm suffering inopportune conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In business management context, the antonym of '**opportunity**' is '**threat**'. An '**opportunity**' by definition is a circumstance where one has possibility of gaining some benefit, and a 'threat' is exactly the opposite - a circumstance where one has possibility of some loss.

However, in day-to-day context, we could take '**adversity**' as antonym for '**opportunity**'. '**Adversity**' here meaning an unfavorable condition/circumstance, whereas '**opportunity**' meaning favorable condition/circumstance.

Comment: I don't see _adversity_ as a very fitting antonym. Example sentences: _Next week we'll have the opportunity to go fishing. My daughter has an interview tomorrow - what an opportunity!_ I think _misfortune_ would be a closer antonym than _adversity_: _My daughter's interview got cancelled - what misfortune! Unfortunately, I can't go fishing next week_.)

Comment: Of course! I had forgotten about SWOT. This makes me realise that in the question I am thinking of a lack of opportunity, rather than something which pushes in the opposite direction to an opportunity. That may not actually be an antonym at all :/

Comment: (+1) Nothing new to add to your answer but **bad luck** and a bunch of possible antonyms at : https://www.powerthesaurus.org/opportunity/antonyms

Comment: @Eilia that is a useful list, although many words seem totally irrelevant, possibly "Barrier" is closest to what I was seeking.

Comment: @glenatron, agree with you, however I could not edit the list!

Answer (score 4):

[Dead-end](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dead-end) is used as both adjective and noun to convey the notion of lack of opportunity. (The Free Dictionary).

To the extent that you’re also considering antonyms for “opportunity” as well as terms describing the absence thereof (e.g., my earlier suggestion of “dead-end,” above), the words ‘opportunities’ and ‘**[pitfalls](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitfall)**’ are [sometimes juxtaposed](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291098-2299%28199901%2946:1%3C34::AID-DDR6%3E3.0.CO;2-A/abstract) to show contrast (if not opposition), especially when discussing those that are hidden (although slightly redundant with 'pitfall')  and/or potential.

Pitfall/noun = a danger or problem that is hidden or not obvious at first (Merriam-Webster)

And to add one more suggestion for the “absence of opportunity” angle  of your quest to go with “dead-end,” since many opportunities are unfortunately ‘wasted,’ perhaps a “**[wasteland](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wasteland)**” could describe the place or state where these wasted opportunities go to languish alongside those that never were.

Wasteland/noun/3 = something, as a period of history, phase of existence, or locality, that is spiritually or intellectually barren.  (Dictionary[dot]com)

Answer (score 0):

I fear it is not quite the same, but perhaps you can use [***misfortune***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/misfortune) or [***contretemps***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contretemps), if you want to imply the sense of an unfortunate event as opposed to a favorable combination of circumstances.

Or perhaps you can use [***inconvenience***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inconvenience?showCookiePolicy=true) or [***hindrance***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hindrance) if you want to imply the sense of a difficulty

Comment: A hindrance may be right, but it doesn't quite convey the simple absence of opportunity, the difference between a wall and a door. I realise that is probably not a true antonym, but I don't know what the correct term for that kind of thing is. If only there was a site where I could find out...

Answer (score 0):

Jeopardy carries the idea of dividing instead of multiplying. Definition of jeopardy: danger of loss, harm, or failure.
legal Definition of jeopardy. 1 : exposure to or imminence of death, loss, or injury. 2 : the danger of conviction that an accused person is subjected to when on trial for a criminal offense.

Comment: You need to [properly cite](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) any definition you get from a dictionary.